# How can I run an Elastic Map Reduce streaming job directly on DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-emr

I'd like to run a streaming job directly on a dynamoDB table.
I know I can run Hive queries using an EMR cluster with hive. But can I do the same with a streaming job?

Is that possible?